# Join table on pattern match

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I have been struggling with this for several hours, so any feedback or advise is very welcome.

I have three tables:

```
users
id    name    email
1     test    test@test.com
2     test2   test2@test.com

pets
pet_id    pet_name    user_id
1         sam         2
2         sally       1

transactions
trans_id    custom
1           1
2           pid2
3           pid1
```

OK, what I would like to do is get transaction data relating to the user. So in the 'transactions' table 'custom' value 1 would relate to 'users' with the id. Thats the simple bit...

'Transactions' with 'pid' relate to the pets id, so 'pid2' relates to sally, whose user is user id 1. So I need to join the transaction table when custom relates to the user id or if its prefixed with 'pid' and the appending value relates to the 'pet_id'.

Here's an example of the result I would like:

Transactions relating to user_id 1:

```
trans_id 1, custom 1
trans_id 2 custom pid2 (this is because the pets owner is user_id 1)
```

Here is where I am with my attempt at the moment:

```
SELECT users.*, transactions.* 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN transactions on users.id = transactions.custom
```

This is where I'm falling over:

```
SELECT users.*, transactions.* 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN pets ON pets.user_id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN transactions on (users.id = transactions.custom 
OR pets.pet_id REGEXP '^pid(transactions.custom)')
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend your table design. Join conditions using computed columns are very bad for performance.

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately there has been limited options with controlling the data and table layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the table design and the prefix pid is fixed you could use

```
OR (
    pets.pet_id = SUBSTR(transactions.custom, 3) 
    AND SUBSTR(transactions.custom, 1 FOR 3) = 'pid')
```

see documentation to [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and because MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

You **HAVE** to refactor Your DB. Current structure will guarantee of speed problems.

Table transactions should looks like

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
  id Int NOT NULL, (id of transaction)
  pet_id Int, (can be null)
  user_id Int (can be null)
  other columns here... 
)
;
```